# Is it possible to reconstruct a command line with Python's argparse?

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

I have a Python script that reads a file containing a command line invocation of some other tool. I'd like to modify the options of this invocation before calling the tool. For example, I might transform:

```
my_util --input file1.txt --option1 red --option2 blue
```

...to this:

```
my_util --input file1_001.txt --option1 red --option3 green
```

(More accurately, I'd be working on the arguments as lists.)

I figured that using the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module would be the easiest way to do this: I could parse the args, change, add or remove the options as I need to, and then reconstruct the command line.

But how do I do the last step? Given the [`Namespace`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object returned by [`parse_args()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args), can I easily reconstruct a list of command line options, such as could be passed to [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Namespace object is just a simple object subclass, so you can get the values out as a dict with `vars`:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```

Or you can assign to a class directly and get the arguments out as class variables:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
...
>>> c = C()
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.parse_args(args=['--foo', 'BAR'], namespace=c)
>>> c.foo
'BAR'
```

It would be fairly easy to use either of these structures to test/replace arguments and pass the results to `Popen`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. The only caveat is that this object won't make the distinction between required positional args and options.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just encountered the same problem. I realized that all I need is a way to iterate over the Action objects. Unfortunately, the internal list is not exposed by ArgParser itself. However, these objects are returned by `add_argument()`, so I can construct my own list. Well, putting `actions.append()` around each call looked like too much typing to me, so I store all options in a tuple:

```py
def add_argument(*args, **kwargs):
    return (args, kwargs)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
options = (
    add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true'),
    add_argument('--author'),
    add_argument('--subject', required=True),
    add_argument('--cache', nargs='?'),
    add_argument('files', nargs=''),
)
actions = []
for (args, kwargs) in options:
    actions.append(parser.add_argument(*args, **kwargs))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

At this point, the options are parsed in `args`, and all `argparse.Action` objects are stored in the `actions` list. I can then iterate over this list and reconstruct the options like this:

```py
cmdline = []
for action in actions:
    value = getattr(args, action.dest)
    if action.required or value != action.default:
        if action.option_strings:
            cmdline.append(action.option_strings[0])
        if action.nargs is None:
            cmdline.append(value)
        elif action.nargs == '?':
            if value != action.const:
                cmdline.append(value)
        elif action.nargs != 0:
            cmdline += value
```

In my specific case, I also wanted to remove some options from the command line. To do that I simply added them separately with a call to `parser.add_argument()` and not through the `options` tuple.